# urxvt: How to switch among tabs like other emultaors?

Tags: urxvt

I'd like to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><Number></kbd> key to switch tabs in urxvt.

Any approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/tabbed` (on my system at least).

On line 312, the sub that control key presses starts (`sub tab_key_press`). It checks `$event->{state}` and a key mask; by default either combinations with `urxvt::ShiftMask` or `urxvt::ControlMask`.

`/usr/lib/urxvt/urxvt.pm` shows other possibilities, e.g. `Mod1Mask` which is most likely the `Alt` modifier.

By default, only shortcuts for walking left or right among tabs are defined. It reads current position (`$idx`), then increases/decreases it by one (`$idx++`/`$idx--`), then sets this value as the new tab index.

With this information, it is easy to modify to

1. Use the Mod1Mask.
2. Read the key number pressed.
3. Set the tab index to the read number.

(with minimal coding experience, not even necessarily Perl; it's mostly copy+paste).

Answer (score 0):

Urxvt is not, by itself, a tabbed terminal. You can use a perl extension to get tabs. It might have some options to change the key binding. see the [FAQ](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.7.pod#Does_it_support_tabs_can_I_have_a_ta) on that.

Comment: Indeed, I use the "tabbed" extension. But the shortcuts are rather inconvenient. Any way to change them?

Comment: @ymfoi Not sure, possibly by editing the source code. I use the window-manager method (xfcewm) so I haven't tried that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with perl, can you figure out how to modify that file?

Comment: What @Daniel said. I'm not a perl-ista, either.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to use the alt modifier, but I did modify the `tabbedex` extension (`/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/tabbedex`) to switch tabs left and right with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and create new tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> still works like before.

I modified the `tab_key_press` function as follows. To change a key binding, you would use its keysym code (here is a list https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h).

```
sub tab_key_press {
   my ($self, $tab, $event, $keysym, $str) = @_;

   if ($tab->{is_inputting_name}) {
      if ($keysym == 0xff0d || $keysym == 0xff8d) { # enter
         $tab->{name} = $tab->{new_name};
         $tab->{is_inputting_name} = 0;
         $self->update_autohide (1);
      } elsif ($keysym == 0xff1b) { # escape
         $tab->{name} = $tab->{old_name};
         $tab->{is_inputting_name} = 0;
         $self->update_autohide (1);
      } elsif ($keysym == 0xff08) { # backspace
         substr $tab->{new_name}, -1, 1, "";
         $tab->{name} = "$tab->{new_name}█";
      } elsif ($str !~ /[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xaf]/) {
         $tab->{new_name} .= $str;
         $tab->{name} = "$tab->{new_name}█";
      }
      $self->refresh;
      return 1;
   }

    if ($event->{state} & urxvt::ShiftMask) {
      if ($keysym == 0xff51 || $keysym == 0xff53) {
         if (@{ $self->{tabs} } > 1) {
            $self->change_tab($tab, $keysym - 0xff52);
         }
         return 1;

      } elsif ($keysym == 0xff54) {
         $self->new_tab;
         return 1;

      } elsif ($keysym == 0xff52) {
         $tab->{is_inputting_name} = 1;
         $tab->{old_name} = $tab->{name} ? $tab->{name} : "";
         $tab->{new_name} = "";
         $tab->{name} = "█";
         $self->update_autohide (1);
         $self->refresh;
         return 1;
      }
   } elsif ($event->{state} & urxvt::ControlMask) {

    if ($keysym == 0x006a){
         if (@{ $self->{tabs} } > 1) {
            $self->change_tab($tab, -1);
         }
         return 1;
    } elsif ($keysym == 0x006b){
         if (@{ $self->{tabs} } > 1) {
            $self->change_tab($tab, 1);
         }
         return 1;
    } elsif ($keysym == 0x0074){
         $self->new_tab;
         return 1;
    } elsif ($keysym == 0xff51 || $keysym == 0xff53) {
         if (@{ $self->{tabs} } > 1) {
            my $idx1 = 0;
            ++$idx1 while $self->{tabs}[$idx1] != $tab;
            my $idx2 = ($idx1 + $keysym - 0xff52) % @{ $self->{tabs} };

            ($self->{tabs}[$idx1], $self->{tabs}[$idx2]) =
                ($self->{tabs}[$idx2], $self->{tabs}[$idx1]);
            $self->make_current ($self->{tabs}[$idx2]);
         }
         return 1;
      }
   }

   ();
}
```